# codeigniter views with dynamic parameters

Tags: codeigniter

I have a edit view whose url is /group/edit/1 where 1 is the group id which is dynamic.

I am validating the form data in controller as :

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
{
    $this->load->view('group/edit', $data);
}
```

How do I pass the id parameter "1" to this view ?

Below option does not work since the url has to be group/edit/1

```
$this->load->view('edit', $data);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're thinking about this wrong. You want to have a view called edit.php and pass the number 1 into it, or perhaps more to the point, you want to get the data for 1 from your model and pass the return value of your model into your view. Consider this:

**controller**

```
function edit($id)
{
    $data['item_info'] = $this->whateverModel->getItem($id);
    $this->load->view('edit', $data);
}
```

Then in your edit view, you can refer to the data like this:

**view**

```
echo $item_info['id'];
echo $item_info['name']; //or whatever you pass back from the model
```

Comment: that is good idea. what if there is a validation error on save and I want to reload the same edit view with the id in the URL "group/edit/1" ? remember I am using self-submit to "group/edit" page. this time the $id in URL is not present and the controller complains about it since $id is no longer valid in "function edit($id)". Also after this URL changes to "group/edit". One option I think is to self-submit to "group/edit/1". Will that be the best practices to follow ?

Comment: Sure, why not? You can have some logic in your `edit()` method that checks to see if it's currently in the middle of a form submission or not. Then you can adjust the view accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
$this->load->view('group/edit/'.$parameter, $data);
```

That would make it load your `1`, as you are simply defining the path of the VIEW document

Per CodeIgniters reference this is the format:
`$this->load->view('folder_name/file_name');`

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/views.html

Not sure if you are confused by routing vs views, here is a quick difference:

If you want http://www.example/group/edit/10 
then you need a route setup, not a view.

If you want http://www.example/ and to display the contents from page main.php (in your views folder) then you do `$this->load->view('main');` inside your primary controller.

Comment: Tried it. It does not work. I get this error message : "Unable to load the requested file: group/edit/10.php"

Comment: Tried it. It does not work. I get this error message : "Unable to load the requested file: group/edit/10.php"

Comment: Do you have a file called 1.php in the folder group/edit/ ?  If not that is your problem.  OR are you describing a 'routing' issue and not a 'view file' issue? You might be confusing the two.

Comment: The parameter "1" is dynamic. I just want to load a view file called "group/edit/1" from *within* a controller where "1" is a dynamic parameter. I am newbie :(

Comment: Are you just trying to pass a variable to the VIEW? I'm officially confused what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am doing. Is this acceptable ?

**Controller action :**

```
function edit($id)
{
$group_q = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM groups WHERE id = ?", array($id));
$group_data = $group_q->row();

    /* Form fields */
    $data['name'] = array(
        'name' => 'name',
        'id' => 'name',
        'value' => $group_data->name,
    );
    $options = array("A", "B", "C", "D");
    $data['group_parent'] = $options;
    $data['group_parent_status'] = $group_data->parent_id;
    $data['group_id'] = $id;

    /* Form validations */
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'trim|required|min_length[2]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
    {
        if ($this->input->post('submit', TRUE))
        {
            $data['name']['value'] = $this->input->post('name', TRUE);
            $data['group_parent_status'] = $this->input->post('group_parent', TRUE);
        }
        $this->load->view('group/edit', $data);
    }
    else
    {
        $data_name = $this->input->post('name', TRUE);
        $data_parent_id = $this->input->post('group_parent', TRUE);
        $data_id = $id;

        if ( ! $this->db->query("UPDATE groups SET name = ?, parent_id = ? WHERE id = ?", array($data_name, $data_parent_id, $data_id)))
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', "Error");
            $this->load->view('group/edit', $data);
        } else {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('message', "Success");
            redirect('account');
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

**View file :**

```
<?php
echo form_open('group/edit/' . $group_id); /***** NOTE THIS STEP *****/
echo "<p>";
echo form_label('Name', 'name');
echo "<br />";
echo form_input($name);
echo "</p>";
echo "<p>";
echo form_label('Parentp', 'group_parent');
echo "<br />";
echo form_dropdown('group_parent', $group_parent_active);
echo "</p>";
echo form_hidden('group_id', $group_id);
echo form_submit('submit', 'Submit');
echo form_close();
```

?>